# SQL Server Service Broker - certificate on endpoint is sufficient?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have databases on two separate instances(not in domain) and i want to use service broker. Is it sufficient to use certificate only on endpoint, some tutorials show using certificate when creating service for example: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb839497(v%3dsql.105) or do i need to use on both endpoint and service?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming network connectivity between the two instances, using a certificate as the shared secret for them to identify and authenticate to each other should be sufficient.

The other place where certificates are used in Service Broker is for transport encryption. You can choose to turn this off, but since you've already got a certificate, you can install that same cert in the user databases participating in the topology and it should be used for the encryption.